# Magnetic field of a solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, inductance

Why, when explaining the magnetic field of a solenoid, are the individual "quasi-rings" split up into two layers with opposite direction of current (see attached pictures; where the x-es and the dots indicate opposite directions). The original picture given clearly states the direction of the current, so why does it "split up into two"?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I haven't understood exactly what you are asking, but if you are asking about the second image, it is just the section of the solenoid. If you imagine to cut a solenoid by length you see exactly that picture; of course the current in this case has two opposite directions. Have you ever seen a real solenoid?

Comment: No, never, only in pictures…

Do you mean that if I were to take a knife and cut the solenoid in the first picture along the line with the L above it, I would see the second picture?

Comment: Yeah exactly, search, online there are thousands of picture of solenoids.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the solenoid is made of current loops next to each other. In the picture the solenoid is cut in half.

Answer (score 1):

that **cross** and **dots** indicates the direction of current "cross" means current enters that point and corresponding "dot "  means current leaves that point - as shown in figure (in my figure  current is in opposite direction to yours but i hope you'll understand)

[image]

solenoid is nothing but stack of rings with same central axis carrying current in same direction (here in CW direction looking from right side )

and that **two loops** in your figure indicates nothing but direction of magnetic field away from the axes of solenoid . remember it looks same as like  we get in the ring

in gist i want to say take a current carrying ring as shown below and put them togeather with there central axis coinciding you will get same magnetic field lines like solenoid

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just cut the solenoid in image 1 from a horizontal diameter and indicate the direction of current again in its wires
Note:- the dots mean current is coming out and the crosses mean its going inside